# Add ul when li has an underscore with javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I want to automatically add `<ul>` when `<li>` has an `'_'` and then remove the `'_'` from `<li>`.

As an example, I want to change this:

```
<nav>
    <div class='LinkList' id='LinkList1'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Look Book</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Pages</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>_Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>_Contact Page</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Info</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>_Success</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>_Error</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

so it looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <div class='LinkList' id='LinkList1'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Look Book</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Pages</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Contact Page</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Info</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Success</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Custom Dashboard</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Categories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Kindly show us what have you done so far? What error/problem are you facing in your implementation?

Comment: How should the algorithm decide whether it should group 2 `li` and add only a single `ul`? What is stopping you from implementing the logic yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#LinkList1 ul li');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#LinkList1 ul');
var counter_check  = 0;
var newItem = document.createElement("ul");     

for(var i=0; li=lis[i]; i++) {
   var array = null;   
   if(counter_check == 0)
   {
      newItem = document.createElement("ul");     
   }

   if(li.childNodes[0].innerHTML[0] == '_')
   {
    counter_check++;

    if(counter_check > 0)
    {
       newItem.appendChild(li);
         //li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
       console.log(li);
       console.log(newItem);
    }

   }
   else
   {
   if(counter_check > 0)
   {
     list[0].insertBefore(newItem,li);
   }

    counter_check=0;

   }

}
```

**/// For expected result in comments**

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#LinkList1 ul li');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#LinkList1 ul');
var counter_check  = 0;
var newItem = document.createElement("ul");     

for(var i=0; li=lis[i]; i++) {
   var array = null;   
   if(counter_check == 0)
   {
      newItem = document.createElement("ul");     
   }

   if(li.childNodes[0].innerHTML[0] == '_')
   {
    counter_check++;

    if(counter_check > 0)https:
    {
       li.childNodes[0].innerHTML = li.childNodes[0].innerHTML.substr(1);
       newItem.appendChild(li);
         //li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
       console.log(li);
       console.log(newItem);
    }

   }
   else
   {
   if(counter_check > 0)
   {
     li.previousElementSibling.appendChild(newItem);
   }

    counter_check=0;

   }

}
```

Comment: this is what I want, thank you very much. but something is missing, can you put `<ul>` children into `<li>` also delete `'_'` from the text?